# Java escaped sequence syntax error

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a string array with lines of codes, so that the program can over-write a portion of existing code once it hits a mark. My problem comes on this line:

```
var finalTitle = (str.replace("()", ("(" + num + ")")));
```

As I am attempting to convert that line into a valid string, I understand that the quotation mark can be somewhat tricky to parse. This is what I have so far:

```
"var finalTitle = (str.replace(\"()\", (\"(\" + num + \")\")));"
```

However, eclipse will not stop complaining that the syntax of this line is incorrect. Does anyone know how to correctly format this line? Or possibly more specifically, how to parse quotation marks into a string?

Here is an example of the string array I am filling. I am going to loop through it with each iteration writing a new line to the .js file:

```
String[] lines = {"var patientTree = getPatientMenuTree();", "var rootNode = patientTree.getNodeById('Patients');", "var str = rootNode.title;", "var num = patientArray.length;", "var finalTitle = (str.replace(\"()\", (\"(\" + num + \")\")));" };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine. Try assigning to a variable:

```
String text = "var finalTitle = (str.replace(\"()\", (\"(\" + num + \")\")));";
```

**Update**

<strike>Near the end of the line you have an extra `};"` that shouldn't be there:</strike>

```
String[] lines = {"...", "...", "...", "..." };" };
```

I see you already fixed that error.

Comment: This does work, which is strange since yes, I fully understand that a string literal needs to be assigned. I was unaware that it will not work in the context of a String array though.

Comment: @Addison: The error is not in the string literal, but in the way you initialize the array. You have some garbage characters just before the closing brace. Probably a copy-paste error.

Comment: I actually added that piece on after pasting on accident since I do not see it in my code. I ended up re-writing the line and it seems to work fine now. Thank you.

Comment: @Addison: In future, please copy and paste the code exactly. Don't copy+paste it then modify it. It's hard to know which errors are the cause of the problem and which errors are due to you modifying the code in the question and introducing new errors.

Comment: Noted. Just so everyone knows, the above code of the escaped string sequence is correct. Just a fluke on my end.